# ERROR Undefined index: numero_mesa in xxxxx on line 16

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5

Estoy rezliando un proyecto en el cuál necesito guardar algunos datos en una base de datos mysql. Ya hice el test de conexión y todo está bien. Pero me envía un error en 4 puntos, aquí solo muestro el primero ya que los demás son el mismo.
Esta es la conexión a la base de datos:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "mi_base_de_datos";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Get the values from the POST request
$numeroMesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
$nombreMesero = $_POST['nombre_mesero'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$fechaHora = $_POST['fecha_hora'];

// Prepare the SQL statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pedidos (numero_mesa, nombre_mesero, mensaje, fecha_hora) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $numeroMesa, $nombreMesero, $mensaje, $fechaHora);

// Execute the statement
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // Successful insertion
    echo "El pedido se ha guardado con éxito.";
} else {
    // Error in insertion
    echo "Error al guardar el pedido. Por favor, inténtalo nuevamente.";
}

// Close the statement and connection
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Y este es el código de la función enviar pedidos:

```
function enviarPedido() {
  var selectMesa = document.getElementById("numeroMesa");
  var numeroMesa = selectMesa.value;

  var selectMesero = document.getElementById("nombremesero");
  var nombreMesero = selectMesero.value;

  if (numeroMesa === "") {
    alert("Por favor, selecciona un número de mesa.");
    return;
  }

  if (nombreMesero === "") {
    alert("Por favor, selecciona un mesero.");
    return;
  }

  var mensaje = "Pedido para la mesa " + numeroMesa + ":\n\n";
  carrito.forEach((producto) => {
    mensaje += "- " + producto.nombre + " (" + producto.variedades.join(", ") + "): $" + producto.precio.toFixed(2) + "\n";
  });
  mensaje += "\nTotal: $" + total.toFixed(2);

  var fechaHora = obtenerFechaHoraActual();
  mensaje += "\nFecha y Hora: " + fechaHora;
  mensaje += "\n\n\nMesero que atendió: " + nombreMesero;

  const notasEspeciales = document.querySelector("#notas-especiales").value;
  if (notasEspeciales !== "") {
    mensaje += "\nNotas especiales:\n" + notasEspeciales + "\n";
  }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "guardar_pedido.php", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // El pedido se guardó correctamente
        alert("El pedido se ha guardado con éxito.");

        // Send the WhatsApp message
        window.open("https://wa.me/+527440000000?text=" + encodeURIComponent(mensaje), "_blank");

        // Limpiar el carrito
        limpiarCarrito();
      } else {
        // Error al guardar el pedido
        alert("Error al guardar el pedido. Por favor, inténtalo nuevamente.");
      }
    }
  };
var params =
  "numero_mesa=" +
  encodeURIComponent(numeroMesa) +
  "&nombre_mesero=" +
  encodeURIComponent(nombreMesero) +
  "&mensaje=" +
  encodeURIComponent(mensaje) +
  "&fecha_hora=" +
  encodeURIComponent(fechaHora);

xhr.send(params);
}
```

La idea es que guarde el pedido en la base de datos antes de ser enviado por whatsapp. Me envía el mensaje de que se ha guardado con éxito asumo porque la conexión es correcta pero en realidad no está guardando nada porque me aparecen los errores Undefined index: numero_mesa. He probado con muchas formas pero no logro resolverlo, así que recurro a ustedes por si tienen alguna idea. Se los agradezco mucho. Saludos

Comment: Cabe destacar que en la parte del html todos los elementos tienen su respectiva etiqueta name. **<select id="numeroMesa" name="numero_mesa" onchange="actualizarNumeroMesa()">** y según yo todo está en orden.

Comment: Has probado a hacer el post sin AJAX? Por ej, con alguna utilidad como Postman.(más que nada por focalizar el error en el PHP o en el AJAX). Por lo que parece, te dice que el índice de $_POST no está definido, por lo que en teoría la llamada no es correcta. Pon al principio de tu PHP algo como `print_r($_POST)` para ver qué te llega, y así vemos algo más de info

Comment: ¿Por qué no usás FormData? (No es sugerencia, es una pregunta)

Comment: El consejo es que depures. Así como sólo mencionas el error del número de mesa y desestimas los otros 3, quita (o comenta) el código de los otros 3. Además de ayudarte a depurar limitando el código a revisar, quedas en posibilidad de colocar en tu pregunta un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

NEcesitas hacer varias Correcciones:

El error "Undefined index: numero_mesa" indica que la variable `$_POST['numero_mesa']` no está definida en el arreglo `$_POST`. Esto puede ocurrir si el valor no se está enviando correctamente desde el formulario al archivo PHP.

1. Asegúrate de que el formulario HTML tenga un campo de entrada con el atributo name establecido en `numero_mesa`. Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="numero_mesa" id="numeroMesa">
```

2. En lugar de utilizar ajax, Verifica que el formulario esté enviando los datos al archivo PHP correctamente. Puedes hacerlo asegurándote de que el formulario tenga el atributo `method` establecido en `post` y que el atributo action apunte al archivo PHP correcto. Por ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="guardar_pedido.php">
    <!-- Resto de los campos del formulario -->
</form>
```

Comprueba si los demás campos del formulario también están generando errores similares. es importante que controles la existencia de todos as variables algo como:

```
if(!isset($_POST['variable'])){
    echo "Error no existe el indice: 'variable' en $_POST";
}
```

Asegúrate de que los nombres de los campos en el formulario HTML coincidan con los nombres de las variables `$_POST` correspondientes en el archivo PHP.

Si sigues experimentando problemas, puedes agregar un `var_dump($_POST);` en el archivo PHP, justo antes de la línea `$numeroMesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];`, para verificar qué datos se están enviando realmente desde el formulario y cómo se están recibiendo en el lado del servidor, a esto de decimos `debug` algo que tambien es importante que vayas probando.